what is use of "jMeter-WebApp" (app service)
what is use of "jMeter-WebApp" (app service). is it related to azure load test tool or azure pipeline (jmeter run tauras)

Could you please elaborate the question a bit? App service resides on Azure portal while DevOps not. jMeter-WebApp is related to load testing, Azure Pipelines can be used to automate the entire CI/CD process, including deploying JMeter .scripts.
